# Recovering multiple of $\phi(N)$ given two private public key pair

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature

Assume $\phi(N) = (p - 1) (q - 1)$ as in the original paper. Suppose that we are using the same modulus $N$ for public and private key pairs $(e_1, d_1)$ and $(e_2, d_2)$. How can we get a multiple of $\phi(N)$ from these two pairs?

Comment: Actually, you need only a single public/private key pair to get a multiple of $\phi(N)$ (actually, $\lambda(N)$, but both will allow you to factor...)

Comment: Having _two_ private/public key pairs will let you find a smaller multiple of $λ(N)$.

Comment: @fgrieu: actually, no it won't - with a multiple of $\lambda(N)$, you can factor, and that'll allow you to compute the smallest positive multiple of $\lambda(N)$ there is :-)

Comment: @poncho: right. Should have written: having _two_ private/public key pairs is likely to let you _easily_ compute a smaller multiple of $λ(N)$, putting you in a better position to factor $N$ or/and find $ϕ(N)$. I should also have noted that $(e_1, d_1)$ is not a valid public/private key pair, for it is lacking $N$.

Comment: @fgrieu: I understand that we can get a multiple using $ed - 1 = -y * \lambda(N)$ or only 1 key pair, but how can we easily compute a smaller multiple of $\lambda(N)$ using two pairs?

Comment: Hint: If $u_1$ and $u_2$ both are non-zero multiples of $v$, then $v$ is a common divisor of $u_1$ and $u_2$. And from $u_1$ and $u_2$ we can often find a multiple of $v$ smaller than $u_1$ and $u_2$ in absolute value.

Comment: BBForage: if you have an answer to your own question, why don't you submit it as an answer (yes, this site allows you to answer your own questions)